# unsigned char string in javascript and creating an equivalent buffer in c++

Tags: javascript, c++, html, canvas, chromium-embedded

I want to send a string containing unsigned characters from JavaScript to c++(using Chromium Embedded Framework).

The unsigned char at the JavaScript side would be the imageData of a Canvas element.

JavaScript code:

```
data = con.getImageData(0,0,mycanvas.width,mycanvas.height).data;

var imageDataString = '';
for(var i =4; i< data.length; i += 4)
{
    imageDataString+=String.fromCharCode(data[i])+ String.fromCharCode(data[i+1]) +String.fromCharCode(data[i+2]);
}
//call the native c++ function
window.cpp.func(imageDataString,mycanvas.width,mycanvas.height);
```

This is how i create an unsigned char buffer from the received string using c++

```
std::string rawString = arguments[0]->GetStringValue().ToString();
unsigned char * raw = new unsigned char[rawString.length()];
memcpy(raw, rawString.c_str(), rawString.length());
```

However, the image received at the c++ side does not match the image sent from JavaScript.

I have tried sending the imageData as an integer array which works but is really slow as arrays must be read index by index(using JavaScript calls) at the c++ side. The above alternative seems to be faster.

Comment: As a start, you probably need `rawString.length() + 1` to copy the null terminator. Perhaps you may need to ditch the "unsigned" as well.

Comment: the string contains raw image data, null terminator shouldn't be copied

Comment: Is it possible that the image contains a null byte?

Comment: We need more of the c++ code specifically with what you are doing with raw to tell what is wrong.

Comment: basically i am creating an openCV Mat object using the raw data and the width and height and displaying it in a window...i can only post more code tomorrow as i have already left my office

Comment: @dmg i dont really understand what you mean by a null byte..if you mean `0` character then yes.

Comment: I mean `\0`. In your line `std::string rawString = arguments[0]->GetStringValue().ToString();` the string will have the data up to the first `\0`.

Comment: i don't think strings contain the null termination character in either c++ or javascript and `memcpy` copies the entire buffer not just uptil the first `\0`