# unsinged int buffer to string conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an array of unsigned integers (ranging from 0-255) to a String so that each unsigned int occupies only one byte i.e. each uint is converted to its equivalent character notation which occupies a single byte.
Code:

```
data = con.getImageData(0,0,mycanvas.width,mycanvas.height).data;

var imageDataString = '';
for(var i =4; i< data.length; i += 4)
{
    imageDataString+=String.fromCharCode(data[i])+ String.fromCharCode(data[i+1]) +String.fromCharCode(data[i+2]);
}
```

In the above code is it guaranteed that each converted uint occupies only one byte?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is your end-goal?

Comment: i need to transfer this data from javascript to c++ using Chromium Embedded Framework. String has worked best so far for me as far as performance is considered.

Comment: i had posted a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069853/unsigned-char-string-in-javascript-and-creating-an-equivalent-buffer-in-c but decided to break it up in two different questiontion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Javascript does not define a `byte` type, and implementations can choose the size of a character used in `string`s.

ECMAScript 6 (currently a draft, but largely implemented by most browsers) does provide for "typed-arrays" with varying element sizes, including `Uint8Array` (and `Uint8ClampedArray`) which covers this usage scenario.

Note that the `.data` property of the `ImageData` object returned from `getImageData` is **already** a `Uint8ClampedArray` (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData )

> Is a Uint8ClampedArray representing a one-dimensional array containing the data in the RGBA order, with integer values between 0 and 255 (included).

So your work is completely unnecessary, as `data` is already consisting of 8-bit elements. Converting the data to a string would only make it use at least twice as much data (as generally, characters are 16-bits wide).

Comment: the size of the cavas.imageData.data is equal to length of the string. Does this mean that each of the pixel data only occupy one byte in the string?

Comment: No, the length of a string is the number of characters in it, similarly the length of an array is the number of elements. Neither is the size of the object in bytes.